# Can't figure out takeUntil behavior

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I can't figure out how proper to stop stream with `takeUntil`.

Interval must start emitting at first, third, etc. click on button, and stop emmitting after every second, fourth, etc. click.

UPD: The purpose of this code is to have kind of 'stopwatch'. On first click, it should start with 0 and count 1, 2, etc. On other clicks it should start / stop counting numbers.

```js
const justIndex = (_, i) => i;
const isOdd = (x) => x % 2;
const isEven = (x) => !isOdd(x);

const buttonClick$ = fromEvent(buttonEl, "click").pipe(map(justIndex));
const resumeClick$ = buttonClick$.pipe(filter(isEven));
const pauseClick$ = buttonClick$.pipe(filter(isOdd));

const intervalFrom = () => 
  interval(500).pipe(
    takeUntil(pauseClick$), // wtf this is not working
    // takeUntil(resumeClick$), // but this is
  );

const resumeInterval$ = resumeClick$.pipe(
  switchMap(intervalFrom),
);
```

[This code at codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/rxjs-stopwatch-problem-yvb1z?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't share the subscription to `fromEvent(buttonEl, "click")` which means that every time you subscribe to `buttonClick$`, `resumeClick$` and `pauseClick$` you're creating a new "click" listener. In turn, this means that when `intervalFrom` is called `takeUntil(pauseClick$)` makes a new subscription to `pauseClick$` that creates a new event listener using `fromEvent` that always starts from `0`.

So what you want to do is to share a single event listener created with `fromEvent` so the click index counter is shared everywhere in your RxJS chain:

```
const buttonClick$ = fromEvent(buttonEl, "click").pipe(map(justIndex), share());
```

Your updated demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/rxjs-stopwatch-problem-forked-4w83h?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

I tested your codesandbox. I dont have a solution but I observed something that might be very important. The `fromEvent` observable emits not only one event when the button is clicked but multiple ones every time. That might mess up your whole set up in the first place.

Try this to verify this:

```js
const buttonClick$ = fromEvent(buttonEl, "click").pipe(
  tap(n => console.log(n))
  );
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it intended behavior of `fromEvent`?

Comment: I don't know about that. I guess it is but I'd agree that it is kind of un-intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't gave much info as **what** you're trying to achieve exactly so I made some assumptions which hopefully are what you wanted or at least close enough that you can figure out what's missing.

```
const TIME_INTERVAL = 500;
const COUNTER_INITIALLY_ON = false;

const DOM = {
  counter: document.getElementById('counter') as HTMLDivElement,
  toggleButton: document.getElementById('toggleButton')
} as const;

const toggleButtonClick$ = fromEvent(DOM.toggleButton, 'click');

const isCounterOn$ = toggleButtonClick$.pipe(
  scan(isCounterOn => !isCounterOn, COUNTER_INITIALLY_ON),
  startWith(COUNTER_INITIALLY_ON)
);

const counter$ = isCounterOn$.pipe(
  switchMap(isCounterOn => {
    if (!isCounterOn) {
      return EMPTY;
    }

    return timer(0, TIME_INTERVAL).pipe(map(x => x * TIME_INTERVAL));
  })
);

const updateDomSideEffect$ = counter$.pipe(
  tap(counter => {
    // side effects are run in a `tap` and are completely isolated
    // from the rest of the streams
    DOM.counter.textContent = counter;
  })
);

updateDomSideEffect$.subscribe();
```

Here's a stackblitz for a live version: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-pniaae?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts

PS: I think the code is descriptive enough that I don't need to explain much but if there's anything that isn't clear just tell me and I can give more details